# get value from array of object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

[image]

I am having trouble accessing elements of an array.
I want to assign project name to local variable projectName
can anyone help me solve how to get the project name from the json structure described above?
Thank you

Comment: Share your code with us and if possible, create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Assuming the array is called `input`: `input[0].project.name` for `'Example123'`, `input[1].project.name` for `'test'` and `input.map(item => item.project.name)` for `['Example123', 'test']`.

Comment: Adding the actual JSON instead of a screenshot would be more helpful.

Comment: thank you for the help and next time i will make sure to add json or code instead screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use array map and return.

```
let data = [{...}, {...}];
let projectNames = data.map(item => {
    return item.project.name;
});
```

Your return value will be an array of strings

```
["Example123", "test"]
```

Comment: Thank you @Joe Tan mapping data works perfect for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you JSON is something like this:

```js
data = [
  {
    project: {
      coverUrl: null,
      description: null,
      id: 'some-guid-1',
      name: 'Example123'
    }
  },
  {
    project: {
      coverUrl: null,
      description: null,
      id: 'some-guid-2',
      name: 'test'
    }
  }
]
```

Then accessing and assigning a project name would require the position, plus the properties:

```js
var projectName = data[0].project.name // 'Example123'
```